# How to decide which type of testing(Manual or automation) required when we get new web application?

Tags: testing, selenium-webdriver, web-applications, automation, manual-testing

How to decide which type of testing(Manual or automation) required for a project or application to test?

What are the parameters we have to consider to select which type of testing(Manual or automation) to test very new application?

Comment: I feel that this question is too wide and general. It could have a lot of answer, each of which would depend upon a different interpretation of the question. It would be better if you can add some context in which this question exists. Is it when you're a new joinee in a company? Or are you starting QA processes from scratch in a company? Or are you trying to change existing processes? A little details would increase the quality of answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on :-

1. **Size of the project**- If the project is large and consist of so many functionalities then automation testing is suggested
2. **How many times you want to test a particular feature**- If the requirement is to test regularly then automation test is best
3. **Font size and image**- This can not be tested through any automation tool so to test this, one should need to do manual testing
4. **To find bugs**- If one needs to find a lot of bugs, Manual testing is suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't have to choose between automation testing and manual testing the way you're asking. The way you're asking it gives me the feeling that the product is already waiting to be tested. In this case you would need to resort to manual testing.

Ideally you would want to have both and even more of automation. Some of the questions that you need to ask are:

1. **Is this a new project or an existing one?** If it's a new project then it's easier to plan for automation from the start. You could start implementing automation tests from the start. If it's an existing project then you'll need time to set up automation + write scripts etc. Then you have to resort to manual testing initially.
2. **Is there any existing team?** If yes, then what are they doing. You need to continue the process instead of suddenly disrupting it for anyone.
3. **How much resources (money+people) do you have?** Do you have manual testing resources? Are they busy or do they have bandwidth? How many automation test resources do you have?
4. **What kind of project is it?** Who does it go to? Does it have human lives depending upon it? Does it need a legal certificate of some kind for being tested?

There's just too many questions based on how your question is currently stated. I hope that this answers your question when we consider it generally. But if you're looking for a particular answer then please consider adding more context.